# How to open Qt .ui file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I am using Qt 5.7.0 and Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. I have integrated Qt with Visual Stdio, using Add-in-Plugin provided in Qt Download Page....

I am able to create and execute Qt project in Visual Stdio, but I am not able to open .ui Form file.

I would like to know if there is any possibility such that, when I click on my .ui file, I will be directed to Qt Designer.

Note: When I try launching QT Designer from Visual Studio, my Visual Stdio freezes and Designer never gets opened.....

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on *.ui file and in open with section set Qt Designer to Default

Comment: I tried that too....not opening ....

Comment: I am not able to Launch Qt Designer from within Visual Studio by default.....I think the problem lies in integration part of Qt Designer with Visual Studio...... Any help....

Comment: I am able to Launch Qt Linguist from within Visual Studio, but not just the Qt Designer alone...